# Is there an easy way to output if statements to STDOUT for debugging?

Tags: ruby, debugging, if-statement, logic

Let's say I have a decently complex if statement:

```
if (f_request <= mmt and f_request >= mt) and (t_request >= s)
```

is there a way to wrap it around a `puts` statement or the like to print out the logic, but instead of the variable names, their values?

For instance rather than having to type:

```
puts "if (#{f_request} <= #{mmt} and #{f_request} >= #{mt}) and (#{t_request} >= #{s})"
```

I could run some method on the original logic (or some simple way to just copy paste it into a method custom method) like:

```
print_logic("if (f_request <= mmt and f_request >= mt) and (t_request >= s)")
```

so that I could get output like:

```
if (6 <= 54 and 6 >= 4) and (3 >= 25000)
```

So I can clearly see how the logic is working and perhaps return the truthness/falseness of the logic as well.

Seems like something that could make debugging a lot easier than using `p` or `puts` to dump variables or having to construct long strings with the logic operators embedded in it.

Thanks

Comment: It would probably be easier to step through the code with a debugger.

Comment: @Jordan Could you expand on that. I was not aware ruby had a debugger. How can I place breakpoints and set "watches" on specific variables and such?

Comment: byebug has those features. Check out [pry-byebug](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/pry-byebug) (you can use byebug on its own but it's better with Pry).

Answer (score 0):

You can combine it with eval like this:

```
irb(main):098:0> string = "if (6 <= 54 and 6 >= 4) and (3 >= 25000) then 4 else 2 end"
=> "if (6 <= 54 and 6 >= 4) and (3 >= 25000) then 4 else 2 end"
irb(main):100:0> puts string
if (6 <= 54 and 6 >= 4) and (3 >= 25000) then 4 else 2 end
=> nil
irb(main):111:0> eval string
=> 2
```

Comment: I would like the variables to auto translate into their values which is more or less what I want. Having to debug each variable is cumbersome, as well as adding all the logic operators to help understand the printed values. Having it resolve its trueness or falseness is a bonus.